# Making a linked list from a binary tree using Preorder Traversal

Tags: c, linked-list, binary-tree, preorder

I want to add elements to a Linked List while Preorder Traversaling on a Binary Tree. I do not want to destroy the BT, just make a copy of the elements in a linked list. This is my code snippet.

```
void Preorder(treeNode *node, Nodelist * head){
    if(node==NULL){
        return;
    }
    //printf("%d\n", node->data);
    head = List_insert(head, node->data);
    Preorder(node->left, head);
    Preorder(node->right, head);
}

Nodelist * List_insert(Nodelist * head, int v)
{
    Nodelist * p = Node_construct(v);
    p->depth = 2222;
    p -> next = head;
    return p;
}

void List_print(Nodelist * head)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", head -> value);
        printf("%d ", head -> depth);
        printf("\n");
        head = head -> next;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

treeNode * Insert(treeNode *node,int data)
{
        if(node==NULL)
        {
                treeNode *temp;
                temp = (treeNode *)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
                temp -> data = data;
                temp -> left = temp -> right = NULL;
                return temp;
        }

        if(data >(node->data))
        {
                node->right = Insert(node->right,data);
        }
        else if(data < (node->data))
        {
                node->left = Insert(node->left,data);
        }
        return node;

}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
        treeNode *root = NULL;
        root = Insert(root, 14);
        root = Insert(root, 15);
        root = Insert(root, 4);
        root = Insert(root, 9);
        root = Insert(root, 7);
        root = Insert(root, 18);
        root = Insert(root, 3);
        root = Insert(root, 5);
        root = Insert(root, 16);
        root = Insert(root, 20);
        root = Insert(root, 17); 

        Nodelist * head = NULL;
        Preorder(root, head);
        List_print(head);

    return 0;
}
```

The above code prints nothing. I think the problem is with the use of head = List_insert(head, node->data); in the preorder function.  Any help with be appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem also in `List_insert`..

Comment: If you wants to modify your BST into Linked list then traverse in postfix order, but that is different matter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `NULL` to the Preorder as the list head. This is passed by value and you cannot alter the head in the main function this way. Instead define Preorder like this:

```
void Preorder(treeNode *node, Nodelist **head)
```

So that you can do:

```
*head = Linst_insert....
```

inside the function to modify the list. Of course, you need to call preorder from the `main` function like this:

```
Preorder(root, &head);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... hope helps

```
Nodelist *Preorder(treeNode *node, Nodelist ** tail) { // use name 'tail' instead of 'head' because you are inserting on the tail, but this functions returns head..

    Nodelist *head;

    if(node==NULL){
        return;
    }
    //printf("%d\n", node->data);
    head = List_insert(tail, node->data);
    Preorder(node->left, tail);
    Preorder(node->right, tail);
    return head;
}

Nodelist * List_insert(Nodelist ** tail, int v)
{
    Nodelist * p = Node_construct(v);
    p->depth = 2222;
    p->next = NULL;
    if (!tail) {
        *tail = p;  // (*tail) is NULL, true when first time List_Insert called
    }
    else {
        (*tail)->next = p;
    }
    return p;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
        treeNode *root = NULL;
        root = Insert(root, 14);
        root = Insert(root, 15);
        root = Insert(root, 4);
        root = Insert(root, 9);
        root = Insert(root, 7);
        root = Insert(root, 18);
        root = Insert(root, 3);
        root = Insert(root, 5);
        root = Insert(root, 16);
        root = Insert(root, 20);
        root = Insert(root, 17); 

        Nodelist * head = NULL;
        head = Preorder(root, &head);
        List_print(head);

    return 0;
}
```